# Warum wird Konjunktiv 1 nicht hier benutzt: "besagt, dass R ... ist

Tags: subjunctive

Aus Sieben Kurze Lektionen über Physik Von Rovelli:

> Einstein stellt eine Gleichung auf, die besagt, dass R der Energie der
>   Materie proportional **ist**.

Warum nicht "...proportional **sei**."?

---

[unterstützender Referenz](https://www.germanveryeasy.com/konjunktiv-i#Indirect%20speech) für akzeptierte [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/44120/24132)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In einer Nebensatzform mit *dass* (dein Beispiel) ist der Konjunktiv in der indirekten Rede optional.

> Einstein stellt eine Gleichung auf, die besagt, dass R der Energie der Materie proportional ist.
>
> Einstein stellt eine Gleichung auf, die besagt, dass R der Energie der Materie proportional sei.

In Konstruktionen, die *laut* oder *zufolge* beinhalten, steht der Indikativ.

> Einer Gleichung von Einstein zufolge ist R der Energie der Materie proportional.

Sowohl "ist" als auch "sei" sind in deinem Beispiel richtig und akzeptabel.

Comment: es hat also nichts damit zu tun, dass das Thema unbelebt ist (Mein Verdacht)

Comment: nein, auch wenn die Gleichung nicht "lebt" und daher auch nichts "sagen" kann, dürfte sie optional trotzdem den Konjunktiv für die indirekte "Rede" benutzen ;) (Nette Theorie übrigens, nur leider falsch)